# Flutter - how to create a framework where i can have Debug and Prod versions where debug version has some way to choose test environment

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to create two different versions of the app. 
- debug 
-prod

for debug, version i need user to select the test environment before anything else begins. i need some way to know what environment user has selected and then load API endpoints config file accordingly.

what's the best way to handle this in flutter?

I have seen in some apps that for iOS, debug options are available in app settings under the standard iOS settings menu , select the app and then see those options in there.

Comment: Are you just trying to know if your app is running in debug or release mode in runtime?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use Flutter Flavours. As the name suggests, you can practically make flavours of the same app based on your need - debug, test, production etc. And not only API end-points, but you can also configure everything else such as app icon, different labels on the screen etc.

As suggested in [this](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-ready-to-go-e59873f9d7de) link, you can have different main.dart file for each flavour. You can read different configuration from JSON file (such as API end-point) and rest of your app will remain same. For example, see below :

[image: Flutter flavors]

[This](https://medium.com/@salvatoregiordanoo/flavoring-flutter-392aaa875f36) is another helpful link.

Comment: awesome buddy.great answer! this is what i was looking for.

Comment: in dev build, i want tester to be able to select the test environment as test1 , test2 or test3. i was thinking to put a screen at the start where user selects environment, which gets stored in shared preferences. then this screen is popped forever for that session. is it a good approach or there are better ways?

Comment: I've never done this but the idea of putting up a selection screen looks good to me. Besides, Tester won't mess-up with the JSON to select the environment any way.

Comment: yes. as environment selection should be done only at the start even before the login flow. if tester needs to change environment after that, app should be killed, relaunched and then it can be changed. btw, i have seen in some iOS apps, companies put such environment selection on app settings itself. i am not able to find how to do that via flutter. but thanks heaps

Comment: You create two config.json files e.g. config_dev.json and _prod. In your main.dart, provide option to select environment. Based on the selection, you call the login screen with the parameter as environment. And write the code to read the appropriate json file.